# TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." when tryng to fetch an API in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to fetch an API on a react project. The console on Mozilla screens the message:TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
More precisely, its a method called when a form is submitted by the user.
Does someone can tell me what's wrong with my code ?

```
async carbonBilan(veh,distance){
        let bilan = await fetch(`https://carbonfootprint1.p.rapidapi.com/CarbonFootprintFromCarTravel?distance=${distance}&vehicle=${veh}`, {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "carbonfootprint1.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "df1e8cd691msh347e6f40838b7a4p12844ejsnbdd339eb9228"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        console.log(bilan)
        this.setState({bilan:bilan,bilanDone:true})
```

Thanks!

Comment: found this one: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/310

Comment: Have you tried to `log` `err.response`?